# Jupyter notebook - invalid syntax when printing [list]

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, python-3.6

I'm new here and it's probably a really dumb question but I'm just starting to learn python and am having with trouble with printing in jupyter notebook. For example:

```
def greatest(list):
    biggest = 0
    for i in list:
        if e > biggest:
            biggest = i 
    return biggest
```

Then I try:

`print greatest([4,23,1])`

And the error message says syntax error:invalid syntax while pointing to the the area just between 'greatest' and ([4,23,1]) in the print command. This has been the case for all times I've tried to print similar things, always with a list of numbers. What can I do?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a reserved keyword. Call it something like `numbers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my code below. There were a few things I corrected, which I have included in the code comments

```
def greatest(numbers):  # Renamed list to numbers, since list is reserved
    biggest = 0
    for i in numbers:
        if i > biggest:   # e here should be i
            biggest = i 
    return biggest 

print(greatest([4,23,1]))  # We need brackets around what we are printing since this is py3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark the question as answered if everything is to your satisfaction :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use [max(list)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) as:

```
 l =  [4,23,1]
 print max(l)
```

**output:**

```
 23
```